# How do I Install Windows 8 or 10 on Surface Pro while Ubuntu is already installed?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8, microsoft-surface-pro

I recently picked up old Surface Pro (1) back up from the many boxes in my bedroom. I had previously installed Ubuntu on it about a year ago because the Windows 8 installation somehow became corrupted.

I am now looking to install the [Windows 10 Preview](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-iso) to test it out.
I am having trouble getting it to boot from USB bootable flash drive though.

I have tried the following steps as outlined [here](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/storage-files-and-folders/boot-surface-pro-from-usb-recovery-device):

1. Hold the volume down button
2. Press the power button
3. Release the volume down after the surface logo appears

Instead of booting from USB it loads up Ubuntu's boot options, "Ubuntu", "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and "System setup" (which boots into the same thing as holding the UP volume key instead of the down volume key).

I'm currently downloading the [Recovery image from Microsoft FOR Windows 8](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/downloadablerecoveryimage?productId=100110440) for my Surface Pro, but I assume its going to continue to give me trouble trying to boot from USB.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem? I'm not to savvy with Linux and I've tried to figure out how to boot from USB in GRUB2 as well with no luck.

Comment: First step would to make sure you have disabled secure boot.

Comment: I've done that already. It didn't make a difference, other than when I had it enabled it wouldn't boot at all and would say invalid key.

Comment: Interestingly enough I had a hard time booting from USB when Windows 8 was already installed on my Surface Pro 2.  I eventually ended up installing Windows 10 on top of the Windows 8 install.

Comment: Another option is to install VMware Player in Ubuntu and then install Win10 in VMware Player. That is how I run Win10 except my host is Win7 - but that should not make any difference. Here is how ==> https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=475A0A48CA6D4035&id=475A0A48CA6D4035%212243

Comment: I'm trying to just get rid of Linux entirely. I appreciate the idea though!

Comment: Running Linux on Microsoft hardware... That's a dance with the devil!

Comment: Why did you remove Windows 8 in the first place? What happened? "Because the Windows 8 installation somehow became corrupted." Would that be because you "previously installed Ubuntu on it"? I'm just curious to know what originally caused Windows to pack its bags and go home. I'm not saying you should not experiment and install other operating systems on *your* hardware; I encourage it. But nothing happens without a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would want Windows installed first and then Linux. This is the common scenario, because (almost) every PC comes with Windows preinstalled. It is also the recommended approach if you start out fresh with a clean disk, because it avoids screwing up the Windows boot manager. That's simply because Linux boot manager is intelligent enough and respectful not to ignore and screw up the setup. The same can't be said about Windows boot manager: it's dumb, ignorant and disrespectful.

You could install Windows on top of Linux. If you can boot into Ubuntu, go ahead and make your partitions. For example leave the second half of the disk empty: move and resize current partitions if necessary. Then create your Windows partitions as you see fit. You can leave them unformatted. Then reboot and run your bootable Windows image (e.g. DVD, USB) and follow setup instructions. Select the previously created partition for Windows install. Drop to console (Shift+F10) and run Diskpart and make additional adjustments if you need or want to. Once install is complete, get ready to boot up with a Live DVD or Live USB with Linux to repair GRUB (or whatever bootloader your Linux system uses). For best results I recommend using the same distro image and version: Ununtu for Ubuntu; Fedora for Fedora.

But instead of all that, and to keep your sanity... and save time... I suggest that you start off fresh and clean. *(One usually does not win time by not reinstalling Linux, oftentimes one ends up losing time due to troubleshooting and fixing the mess left after Windows blasts through the neighborhood and tips over every garbage can.)* So backup your Ubuntu files and clean your disk. Then start by restoring Windows 8, and then install latest Ubuntu (or other Linux distro of your choice). Disable secure boot if it gives you a hard time.

You can use a Linux Live system for cleaning the disk. A quick format should do it. You should also have your Windows boot image ready to go. So prepare all that beforehand or be sorry later. I would recommend using bootable USB flash drives for both. It makes it much quicker to load than a CD or a DVD.